# Access token expires in 60 minutes. Need to extend or refresh token but no refresh token available. Any other method to get this to work?

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, access-token

I'm working on a windows application wherein, I'm using modern authentication to Exchange online and using EWS API for OAuth 2.0 authentication. To retrieve the access token I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Client library.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ClientId)  
    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)                                                                   
    .WithTenantId(TenantId)
    .Build();

var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

AuthenticationResult authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(accessToken);
```

My problem is, the access token expires after 60 mins. After that the service object throws "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" error. Is it possible to modify the lifetime of access token or can we set the access token to never expire?

I did not get any refresh token with access token. So not sure how to continue to process without going through UI login window again and again every hour.

Comment: "can we set the access token to never expire?" - that's not really a good thing to do, securitywise.

Comment: Yes, but this is for testing. Even if its not never expire, i wish we could just refresh token after 60 minutes and we are not getting any refresh tokens.

Comment: Why EWS and not Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with a Confidential Client Application, but a Public Client Application object can created like this:

```
var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(YourAppId)
    .WithAuthority(YourAuthority)
    .WithRedirectUri(YourRedirectUri)
    .Build();
```

That object can be used to request a token, and it can be kept in memory and used to access the TokenCache:

```
AuthenticationResult authResult;
var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();

if (accounts.Any())
{
    authResult = pca.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.First()).ExecuteAsync().Wait());
}
else
{
    authResult = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Wait());
}
```

If the Public Client Application object goes out of scope, the TokenCache goes with it.

The Public Client Application object has BeforeAccess and AfterAccess callbacks which can be used to persist the TokenCache.